# Empty space detection

Tags: tensorflow, image-recognition

I'm looking for a TensorFlow model detecting empty spaces on the images. I need to add my company logo to this empty area so there shouldn't be any faces or objects in this area.
Also, I would be thankful for information if the is any existing solution for doing that (can be paid)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for a *foreground/background segmentation model* (also called *image matting*). There are several ways to do this.

Here's one option for a Tensorflow model: https://github.com/adumrewal/imageMatting

Paperswithcode is a website compiling paper implementations along with their benchmark scores. You can find several tensorflow-based models on their [Image Matting leaderboard](https://paperswithcode.com/task/image-matting/latest).

However, if using Tensorflow isn't 100% necessary, then I'd go with something like [*PaddleSeg*](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleSeg) instead, which provides more well-tested implementations for applications like this, whereas running research repositories can often be a bit frustrating.